# ¿Que tengo mal para que no me deje copilar o que es lo que me falta?

Tags: c++, c, estructuras-de-datos, dev-c++, estructuras

Estoy programando un juego en c/c++ y a la hora de entrada de jugadores cuando les pido los datos tengo error de compilación para guardar los datos de los mismos.

Bueno en el pedazo de código compartido se encuentra adentro de un switch con la opción de agregar un nuevo jugador al juego.

Deje comentado en el código de abajo que es lo que pasa con cada opción donde me tira errores.

Antes de pasar a el codigo les voy a dejar el arreglo de estructura que hice y también las librerías:

```
// =============== Librerías  ===============
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

// =============== ESTRUCTURAS  ===============

struct jugador {
    char alias  [5];
    char nombre [20];
    char apellido [20];
    unsigned cedula [11];
    unsigned monto [1000];
    int edad;
}j[10];
 ``
```

````
    case ('R'): case ('r'): //ops Registrar nuevo jugador
        system ("cls");
        if (cantjugadores == 10) {
            cout << "\aLa mesa de juego se encuentra llena y no admite mas jugadores";
        }
        else {
            cout << "Ingrese su ALIAS: ";
            cin >> j[i].alias;
        
            cout << "\Ingrese su nombre: ";
            cin >> j[i].nombre;
        
            cout << "\nIngrese su Apellido: ";
            cin >> j[i].apellido;
        
            cout << "\nIngrese su Cedula: ";
            scanf ("%d", &j[i].cedula);  //con esto me guarda un valor basura.
            //cin.getline (j[i].cedula, 11, '\n');  con esto no compila.
        
            cout << "\nIngrese su Monto Inicial: ";
            scanf ("%d", &j[i].monto);      //Me guarda valor basura
            //cin.getline (j[i].monto, 1000, '\n');      No compila
        
            cout << "\Ingrese su Edad: ";
            cin >> j[i].edad;
            cantjugadores++;
            }
    break; ```
````

**El error que me tira al compilar con el cin.getline(); es el siguiente:
[Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_istream::getline(unsigned int [12], int, char)'**

Otra cosa que me gustaría saber es como guardar todos los jugadores ya que cuando vuelvo a agregar otro jugador me sustituye el jugador guardado (viejo) por el nuevo y no estaria agregando todos los jugadores.

Comment: la función `cin.getline()` resive dos pasametros, el `char *` y el tamaño +1 de lo que quieres almacenar. Ejemplo:  `char nombre[10]; cin.getline(nombre, 11);`

Comment: Si lo se, antes lo tenia así en el código, pero seguía sin compilar ahora lo volví a editar y lo deje como antes.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que te guarde un valor "Basura" porque el buffer tenga almacenada información, intenta "limpiar" el buffer de teclado.
Intenta con fflush( stdin ); antes de guardar la cedula y también antes de guardar el monto

Comment: Intente con el fflush( stdin ); y tampoco me funciono, gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

No es porque tu estás leyendo con formato "%d" que es para enteros y tu dato "cédula" creo que es un char de 11 caracteres, no soy bueno en C++ pero puede que sea eso no? deberías de especificar tu "unsigned int" en tu struct y no ponerle una cantidad de caracteres "[11]".